# SQLite SELECT with CASE doesn't return expected output

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is an issue that has been racking my brain for several days. The purpose of this statement is to return "0" if no rows are found in the table or if there are rows to return the latest (basically the maximum) bottomDepth.

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(_id) 
WHEN 0 THEN '0' ELSE BottomDepth END AS 'BottomDepth'
FROM Stratigraphy WHERE guid='2cd0b6bb-41f2-407e-b6e8-c032824d550f'
AND (InstatanceState IS null OR InstatanceState != 5) AND  (4 IS null OR _id < 4)
AND (DeletedFlag IS NULL OR DeletedFlag < 1) 
ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

The problem is when there are rows, it's not returning the latest bottomDepth but the first bottomDepth in the table (almost like it's ignoring the WHERE clause). I'm a SQL novice so could someone explain why this is returning 2.0 and NOT 4.0?

[image: Here's the table as normal]
[image: Here's the SQL query run with the result]

Comment: `4 IS null` what is this?

Answer (score 0):

By using `MAX(BottomDepth)` in the select list SQLite will return the row that contains the max `BottomDepth`, so there is no need for `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.
This is documented behavior which is explained in [Simple Select Processing](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(BottomDepth), '0') AS BottomDepth,
       <other columns here>
FROM Stratigraphy 
WHERE guid = '2cd0b6bb-41f2-407e-b6e8-c032824d550f'
  AND (InstatanceState IS null OR InstatanceState <> 5) AND  (? IS NULL OR _id < 4)
  AND (DeletedFlag IS NULL OR DeletedFlag < 1)
```

I changed `4` to `?` in `4 IS null` because I believe this is a typo. Change it to the correct column name.

Comment: @MattCasey fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.